# Laravel 4 Url routing point

Tags: url, laravel, laravel-4, routes, point

I encountered a small problem about the urls in Laravel 4, I created a route with the username variable whose value may contain points(dots). here is the example:
***localhost:8888/users/joe.doe***

the problem is that it always shows me the error 404

is there a way to activate the point in url?

```
Route::get('{username}', function() {
   return $username;
});
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-parameters - and apply a reguler route constraint.